# New(er) to Java - need to get this array working... not sure how :(

Tags: java, arrays, calendar

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Calendar31 {
static String strDays = " %2d  ";

public static void main(String[] args) {

        String getYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Year to Show: ");
        int year = Integer.parseInt(getYear);   
        String startingDay = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Starting Day (0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday): ");
        int startDay = Integer.parseInt(startingDay);

        String[] months = new String[12];
            months[0] = "January";
            months[1] = "February";
            months[2] = "March";
            months[3] = "April";
            months[4] = "May";
            months[5] = "June";
            months[6] = "July";
            months[7] = "August";
            months[8] = "September";
            months[9] = "October";
            months[10] = "November";
            months[11] = "December";

    for (int y = 0; y <= 11; y++) {
        System.out.println("          " + months[y] + "   " + year);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat");

        for (int x = 0; x < startDay; x++){
            System.out.print("     ");
        }

        for (int d = 1; d <= getNumDays(1, year); d++){
            System.out.printf(strDays, d);
            if ((d + startDay) % 7 == 0){
                System.out.println();
            }
        }   
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();   
    }   
}

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
        return ((year % 4 == 0)&& (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
    }

    public static int getNumDays(int m, int year) {
        int[] numDays = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
        int retval = numDays[m-1];
        if ((m == 2) && (isLeapYear(year))){
            retval++;
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

So, I have this code. The project is to make a java program that displays the yearly calendar depending on the year you input and the starting day of the first month... made another method to determine leap year because some idiot a long time ago decided we need that extra 1/4 day in a year... so that does work when the month is the second month.  In that method, there's the array with 12 entries, those 12 being Jan, Feb, Mar, so on.  Now, in the main block of code up top there is the line :

```
for (int d = 1; d <= getNumDays(1, year); d++) {
```

where the 1 is, that pulls the first int from the array in getNumDays... for some reason, I cannot figure out where I went wrong, but the 1 needs to go away and in its place we need 'm', as defined in getNumDays.  But no matter what I cannot figure out the syntax needed for this... I'm sure its something simple.  Any quick help out there?  Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using the Calendar API? Why are you using arrays instead of Enums? How does your program determine what month it is, if it does?

Comment: This is my intro to java class and we arent allowed to use the calendar api... sucks.

Comment: I suggest you look into Enums and switches, you probably don't want an array when you are using constants like names of months.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just change the "1" you reference to "y"?  As in:

```
for (int d = 1; d <= getNumDays(y, year); d++){
```

After all, the outer loop  counts from 0 to 11 and assigns the value to y.  Then, you can just use that value to call the getNumDays function and return the proper number of days in month "y".

Also, you may want to consider using tabs instead of a predefined number of spaces.  This will ensure that your columns line up.  For example:

```
System.out.println("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");

    for (int x = 0; x < startDay; x++){
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I changed that and it gives me an out of bounds exception on the array... does not seem to work in that the int[] = {31, 28, 31, ...} is determining the number of days... and that is called numDays but y does not work.

Comment: I think you are getting the out of bounds exception in the line:
int retval = numDays[m-1];
you just need to say
int retval = numDays[m];
The error occurs because when you send 0 to the function it tries to find numDays[-1] which doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay... so the good news is that it DOES work, and the month output displays as normal. Bad news is it does not accurately calculate leap year... oh well. Partial credit is better than no credit and the deadline is in a few hours. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe isLeapYear only needs  return (year % 4 == 0);

Comment: @Angelo - actually, his logic looks correct at first glance because according to the Gregorian calendar, February has 29 days when (a) the year is divisible by 4 but not divisible by 100 or (b) the year is divisible by 400.  This is because it takes the earth 365.26 days to make one complete revolution around the sun.  If we kept it at 365 days, with no leap year, then eventually we would be celebrating Christmas and New Years in the fall and Halloween would fall during the Summer.  Regarding the code, however, I'm not seeing why it's not returning the correct number of days.

Comment: Oh - duh.  Just saw it.  February is when m = 1, not 2.  So just change the line `code if ((m == 2) && (isLeapYear(year))){` to `code if ((m == 1) && (isLeapYear(year))){ `